# Token pasting does not seem to be working with C++ macros

Tags: c++, macros

I am trying to mimic template behavior in C++ using macros. For instance, if I wanted a list of int*, then I would do something like this:

```
typedef int* IntPtr;
List_DEFINE(IntPtr)
```

Note that List_DEFINE(IntPtr) has no semicolon because it is a macro. I have written my list "class" (really just a couple of structs with method pointers), and tested it before making it a macro. I am now trying to "macrotize" my code, and I am running into problems. I have defined my macro like this:

```
#define List_DEFINE(t) \
struct List_##t_Node { \
...
```

In the example above, I thought that ##t would be replaced with whatever was passed into t, but that does not seem to be the case. If I define two different types of lists, I get the following error:

```
test.cpp:85: error: redefinition of ‘struct List_t_Node’
test.cpp:75: error: previous definition of ‘struct List_t_Node’
```

So in the above example, I would want struct List_IntPtr_Node to be generated, but instead List_t_Node is generated. Why?

Comment: You should look at the output of the preprocessor.  For instance, if you're using GCC, you should use the `-E` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
List_##t##_Node
      //^^
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept this in 8 minutes :P Could you possible explain the rules for when the 2nd pair of #'s is neccessary. For instance, Which of these would be valid? `List_##t list` or `List_##t## list`

Comment: @Max: `##` is a concat operator, it'll concat the left to the right, so when you need to join 3 things, is when you'll need two

Answer (score 3):

The token after `##` is `t_Node`, so the preprocessor pastes `List_` to `t_Node`.

To have `t` replaced by the macro parameter it has to be a single token, which can then be pasted to a preceding `List_` and following `_Node`:

```
#define List_DEFINE(t) \
   struct List_ ## t ## _Node { \
   ...
```