# Token pasting and __LINE__

Tags: c++, file, macros

I'm writing a simple macro to show TRACE information.

This is what I'm using ,

```
#ifdef __DEBUG__
#define TRACE  { PrintErrorMsg("Trace exception at " __FILE__  "LineNo:"##(__LINE__) "Function: " __FUNCTION__ " " );}
#else 
#define TRACE 
#endif
```

This is working with **FILE**, but it doesn't seems to work with **LINE** , 
Any idea how could I deal with this. I already tried stringing operator too.Which is as
bellow.

```
#ifdef __DEBUG__
#define TRACE  { PrintErrorMsg("Trace exception at " __FILE__  "LineNo:"#(__LINE__) "Function: " __FUNCTION__ " " );}
#else 
#define TRACE 
#endif
```

and without parms and with double parms , ex - `__LINE__` or `((__LINE__))`
Any idea how could I deal with this problem?

And I come up with this,

```
#ifdef __DEBUG__
#define ERROR_MSG_BUF_SIZE 1024
#define TRACE  { char * error_msg_buffer = new char[ERROR_MSG_BUF_SIZE]; \
                 sprintf(error_msg_buffer,"Trace Exception at file: %s ,Line : %d , Function %s \n",__FILE__,__LINE__,__FUNCTION__);\
PrintErrorMsg(error_msg_buffer );\
delete[] error_msg_buffer;}
#else 
#define TRACE
```

But I want to do it without using sprintf , just only by stringing and token pasting.
Any idea?

```
#endif
```

--Thanks in advance--

Comment: Why do you have parentheses around `__LINE__`?

Comment: because it belongs all to `__LINE__` not only to '_'. 
Because I refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454973/token-pasting-does-not-seem-to-be-working-with-c-macros

Comment: Umm, `__LINE__` is the token. You want `#__LINE__`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I tried that way too, no results

Comment: Always tell people what "doesn't work" is. Also for your temporary fix, use `std::string` instead of `new char[]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need this kind of silliness, unfortunately.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRACE2(f,l) printf("I am at file: " f " and line: " #l "\n")
#define TRACE1(f,l) TRACE2(f,l)
#define TRACE() TRACE1(__FILE__, __LINE__)

int main(void)
{
    TRACE();
    TRACE();
}
```

> I am at file: test.cpp and line: 9
>   I am at file: test.cpp and line: 10

Comment: Any insight for why double macro is required?

Comment: Because you need the macro to itself be replaced, so you need it to be processed twice.

Answer (score 19):

When you try to stringize something with `#x`, that `x` must be a macro parameter:

```
#define FOO #__LINE__ /* this is not okay */
#define BAR(x) #x     /* this is okay */
```

But you cannot simply say `BAR(__LINE__)`, because this will pass the token `__LINE__` into `BAR`, where it is immediately turned into a string without expansion (this is by design), giving `"__LINE__"`. The same thing happens with the token-pasting operator `##`: expansion of their operands never happens.

The solution is to add indirection. You should always have these in your codebase somewhere:

```
#define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE_SIMPLE(x)
#define STRINGIZE_SIMPLE(x) #x

#define CONCAT(first, second) CONCAT_SIMPLE(first, second)
#define CONCAT_SIMPLE(first, second) first ## second
```

Now `STRINGIZE(__LINE__)` turns to `STRINGIZE_SIMPLE(__LINE__)` which gets fully expanded to (for example) `#123`, which results in "123". Phew! I leave `STRINGIZE_SIMPLE` around on the off chance I want the original behavior. So your code would be something like:

```
#include <iostream>

#define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE_SIMPLE(x)
#define STRINGIZE_SIMPLE(x) #x

#define TRACE()                                                 \
        PrintErrorMsg("Trace exception in " __FILE__            \
                      " at line number " STRINGIZE(__LINE__)    \
                      " in function " __FUNCTION__ ".")

void PrintErrorMsg(const char* str)
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    TRACE();
}
```

Comment: This code and `__FUNCTION__` is failing on Mingw64 version. 
I think it's a bug, and it works on visual C++. 
Somebody who more experienced please report it.
Does you try this code with g++ ?

I think `__FUNCTION__` wasn't defined in mingw headers. That may be the reason.

Comment: @sandundhammika: `__FUNCTION__` is non-standard so it's use isn't guaranteed. It's not a bug. The C99 standard (and therefore C++11) defines `__func__`, but as a variable, not a string literal. I believe GCC expands `__FUNCTION__` to `__func__`, which would cause the error. You should split your function up to accept the function name as an argument, then both a string literal and the `__func__` variable can be passed to it.